# Бот aiogram непонятная ошибка при создании машины состояний

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

пишу бота на aiogram, создаю машину состояний, которая запускается сразу после старта. Необходимо забрать два наименования: Login_user and time_user
Бот запускает корректно, но после команды старт выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher
from create_bot import dp, bot
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    login_user = State()
    time_user = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state=None)
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await  FSMAdmin.login_user.set()
    await message.reply('Привет, введи логин')

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['Text'], state=FSMAdmin.login_user)
async def login_def(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['login_user'] = message.text
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await reply.message('Отлично, я запомнил. Теперь нужно выбрать время суток')




def register_handlers_user(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(start, commands=['start'])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле инициализации диспетчера нет скобок у MemoryStorage()

Answer (score 0):

```
    # @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state=None)
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Привет, введи логин')
    await  FSMAdmin.login_user.set()

# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.login_user)
async def login_def(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['login_user'] = message.text
    
    await message.reply('Отлично, я запомнил. Теперь нужно выбрать время суток')
    await FSMAdmin.next()

# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.time_user)
async  def time_user(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['time_user'] = message.text
    await message.reply('')
    await FSMAdmin.finish()



def register_handlers_user(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(start, commands=['start'], state='*')
    dp.register_message_handler(login_def, state=FSMAdmin.login_user)
    dp.register_message_handler(time_user, state=FSMAdmin.time_user)
```

и потом просто импортируешь register_handlers_user в основной файл

Answer (score -1):

у тебя в функции login_def написано

```
await reply.message('Отлично, я запомнил. Теперь нужно выбрать время суток')
```

а надо

```
await message.reply('Отлично, я запомнил. Теперь нужно выбрать время суток')
```

Answer (score -2):

Так сходу сложно ответить, но утебя как будто здесь ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть у тебя должно вот так выглядеть:

`self.dispatcher.storage.get_state(self, chat=chat, user=user)`